Velocity due to centripetal acceleration
If a acceleration is acting in 90 degrees to a velocity the velocity component due to acceleration must change the magnitude of velocity as we know it makes a right angle triangle why is it not the case of centripetal acceleration . If the velocity acts such that it makes a isosceles triangle then I understand how the direction only changes.

This question is similar to: Intuition on centripetal acceleration. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Keep in mind that vector addition can result on two things: a change in magnitude and/or a change in direction. In particular, note that a change in direction is possible without change in magnitude of you add just the right vector. And that is essentially what is happening, albeit with infinitesimal vector differences, in the case of centripetal acceleration. So, only a change in the velocity direction happens, not in the velocity magnitude.
